# What's the difference between CAAnimation, CABasicAnimation, CAKeyFrameAnimation and the standard [UIView beginAnimations] Core Animation stuff?

Tags: iphone, core-animation

Are all these things basically the same? I did the exact same thing now with CAAnimation rather than using an simple UIView animation block. What are the big differences?

Answer (score 9):

They are all interfaces to Core Animation. The various interfaces generally trade off simplicity versus control. Everything that you can do with a UIView animation block can be done with a CAKeyFrameAnimation, but you'll probably write more code to do to.

Comment: I see... so UIView animation blocks are the most simple, while CKeyFrameAnimation is the most complex of them all?

Comment: A UIView animation block pulls together the ideas of animation groups, transitions and transactions into a single interface, and it defines that interface in terms of the view. CAKeyFrameAnimation is likely the most complex to use of the concrete classes, but of course you could reach even further down and implement your own CAPropertyAnimation to get even more control (such as more complex timing), or you could implement your own CoreImage filters to create new CATransitions. So there are definitely more complex things than CAKeyFrameAnimation. But they're all part of the same framework.